# Counting the frequency of a list of pairs in an RDD with pyspark

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am trying to calculate the frequency of some pairs (stored in a list) in an RDD where each element is a list of strings. Teh RDD has this form:

```
[['protectuаsky', 'stoprussia', 'ukraineunderattaсk'],
 ['russianinvasion',
  'standwithukraine',
  'ukraineunderattack',
  'ukrainewillwin',
  'putinisawarcriminal',
  'stopputin',
  'russianukrainianwar',
  'russiagohome',
  'россиясмотри',
  'нетвойне'],
 ['russianukrainianwar', 'china', 'taiwan'],
 ['anonymous', 'oprussia', 'ddosecrets'],
 ['nft', 'mint']
 ...
]
```

My goal is to compute, for example, the frequency of the pair ('stoprussia','nft')

Comment: do you mean that you want the frequency of the occurrence of the two terms at the same list in the global list or you want the frequency of each term 'stoprussia' then 'nft'?

Comment: I want to calculate the frequency of the pairs in the RDD. Let's make a better example: my rdd will be like [ ["A","B","C"],["A","D"],["C","B","D"],["C","E"]].         The frequency of the pair ("B","C") should be 2 (first and third elements in the RDD.

Comment: Rereading you comment, I need the first thing you said. Keep in mind that the one you called global list is an RDD and to perform this operation I have to use the map reduce paradigm in order to ha it scalable with data

Answer (score 0):

```
 def frequency(content,element):
        fre = 0
        for i in content :
            if set(element).intersection(set(i)) == set(element) :
                fre += 1
        return fre
```